# Getting 'gulp pipe is not a function' when copying example from npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to use `gulp-sftp`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sftp) to SFTP files to my remote server.

I've installed the package and have the following on my `gulpfile.js` - verbatim from the example (except for the login details, obviosuly).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sftp = require('gulp-sftp');
 
gulp.task('sftp', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/*')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: 'website.com',
            user: 'johndoe',
            pass: '1234'
        }));
});
```

however when I run this task I get the error:

> TypeError: file.pipe is not a function

Would anyone know what I can do to fix this?

PS: When I run `gulp -v` I see 2 versions:

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

Comment: I see `gulp-sftp` was last published five years ago - perhaps it is not compatble with gulp v4.  Maybe try https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp which works for me.

Comment: @Mark does Vinyl work with SFTP? I couldn't see anythign on there.